# Screeninfo Package causes DPI Awareness Error using PyQt6

Tags: python, scaling, dpi, pyqt6

I am trying to determine the resolution of the primary monitor within a PyQt6 application. Unfortunately, that causes the following error:
qt.qpa.window: SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2) failed: COM error 0x5: Access is denied.

Qt's default DPI awareness context is DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2. If you know what you are doing you can overwrite this default using qt.conf (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html#configuring-windows)

While this error only shows up twice, when starting the application within VS Code, when running the application as a standalone executable created with pyinstaller, the error appears infinitely causing the application to loop. This even results in the Windows OS to lag like crazy. On top of that Windows is not able to close the application, not even through the task manager. In the end, I had to brute force the shutdown via power button.

I know that it is the screeninfo package causing the error, because removing it removes the error. However, I need to use screeninfo in order to determine the resolution of the primary monitor like so:

```
from screeninfo import get_monitors

monitors = get_monitors()
for monitor in monitors:
    if monitor.is_primary:
        primary_monitor = monitor
        break
```

I need the resolution to set the size of my UI Elements to take up the same relative space on every computer.

On a side note, Qt documentation says that it supports DPI aware scaling by default. However, when not using relative sizing, my application looks different on monitors with different resolution. So, how is that supposed to work?

This is my first complete application built with python btw, so I have basically no idea what I am doing..

Comment: Qt already provides the [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html) API to query the available screens, so you should use it. Note that that shouldn't be that fundamental for your UI, and it's possible that this requirement is just caused by bad layout management (you are using layout managers, aren't you?) or improper size settings.

Comment: That is correct, I first used QScreens, but it seems like it is not possible to find virtual displays created by Wireless Display like that. And no, I am actually not using layout managers, I felt like I had more control without them. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Are you completely sure about that QScreen issue? Note that in some circumstances you may need to check all virtual siblings of each QScreen instance listed by `QApplication.screens()`; still, it *may* be an issue or bug, and you should consider doing some research on that topic (possibly by creating a question here or even by reporting a bug after thorough testing). And, yes, not using layout managers is almost always a mistake; the common feeling is that they are difficult to use, don't work as expected, give limited control over the wanted layout and provide limited customization.

Comment: 99.9% of the time, these are assumptions caused by limited experience and lack of knowledge of all aspects required to achieve a proper layout, which is what Qt already implements, and thoroughly. In fact, there are very few cases for which avoiding layouts is considered acceptable (or even required), and that's a choice done with *full* awareness of its implications and after considering existing alternatives. In reality what is needed for the UI can almost always be achieved by properly using widget and layout capabilities, such as size hints, size policies, spacer items and stretch factors.

Comment: I suggest you to do a more thorough research on all these aspects (including proper understanding of how Qt layouts work, starting from the basic QLayout and QLayoutItem classes), and if you still cannot achieve what you actually want, then post a question here with a proper [mre], explaining the issue and possibly showing an image (even a mockup) of the wanted result. I'm quite sure that a layout-based solution can be found, instead of relying of arbitrary assumptions while possibly underestimating important aspects you may not be aware of.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I will look into layout managers. For the screen resolution issue I went back to using QScreen, because wireless display is quite a niche problem and most likely does not matter for my application. Still could not figure out why screeninfo causes the DPI Awareness Error and how to prevent that though.

Comment: It's probably related to [this issue](https://github.com/rr-/screeninfo/issues/73) as there seems to be a memory leak: screeninfo doesn't seem to correctly release some resource, and that probably doesn't play well with Qt which needs priority access to those aspects. A possible alternative could be to try to do the query of screeninfo in a separate process and wait for its returned values, but, as said, if you're doing it for layout purposes, then it's a *wrong reason*, and you shouldn't do it in the first place. If you have specific Qt layout requirements, solve *those* requirements.

Comment: This problem first occurred in PyQt 6.5.x. It is also seen if your application merely imports pyautogui.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass screen width and height to methods, you need to get the screen's pixel size from the active `QApplication`. Otherwise, it won't work.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
print(f"Width: {app.primaryScreen().size().width()}")
print(f"Height: {app.primaryScreen().size().height()}")
```

However, if you still want to try, you can directly pass `QApplication().primaryScreen()...` and not the object. But, calling `QApplication()` will create a new `QApplication` object (and, if you already have one, I think that wouldn't be a good idea).